# Create DataSource lazily and transaction manager

Tags: java, spring

I have a DB access module that interacts with multiple types of data sources.

Some higher modules use the DB module without interacting with JDBC data source. Therefore, I would like the data source to be defined as lazy. However, I also define a transaction manager which I can't define as lazy since it is not a direct dependency in my code. Since the transaction manager depends on the data source, the latter is always created.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
        //create data source
    }

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() throws Exception {
        DataSourceTransactionManager txManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
        return txManager;
    }
}

@Lazy
@Repository("FundRepository")
public class MyRepository {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
         jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Are transactions opened in paths that do not interact with the datasource?

Comment: @BoristheSpider No

Comment: Something like [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.html) ought to work then.

Comment: Why are you concerned about the DataSource-Creation? In my opinion that contains only a few configuration data, at least if you use it correctly together with a Transactionmanager. In that case all connection-management is handled by the TM. And the connections are the resource you should be concerned about.

Comment: @aschoerk I'm using connection pooling with C3P0 and I would like to have an initialized pool at startup for the modules that do access the DB. The only solution I can think of right now is to have a custom C3P0 properties file for the modules that don't use the DB, which doesn't initialize the pool at startup.

Comment: So you have multiple datasources and therefore multiple pools and those are used by the transactionmanager?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm not sure if that will prevent connections to be opened when connection pooling is used. C3P0 (which is what I use) will still open connections according to its config.

Comment: That depends on your config - if your pool only creates on demand then caches then it would work.